# I structured my HOC so it could be invoked twice. How do I connect redux in this context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components

I structured my HOC so it could be invoked twice "**functional programming**". Now I'm failing to connect redux to get state and some functions. Please help how do I connect redux in this context. Everything I have tried has resulted in an error being thrown.

```
import React from "react"

export default (WrappedComponent) => {

  return (mapFunctions) => {
    return function({ ...props }) {
      const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

      // typical functionality of the HOC
      //search function 
      const handleSearch = (e) => {
        let filter,
          table,
          tableRow,
          tableCells,
          txtValue,
          results = [];

        filter = e.currentTarget.value.toLowerCase();
        table = document.querySelector(`#${mapFunctions.tableID}`);
        tableRow = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        Array.from(tableRow).forEach((row, index) => {
          tableCells = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

          if (tableCells) {
            txtValue = tableCells.textContent || tableCells.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
              return mapFunctions.searchFuncReasult === "array" ?
                results.push(row) :
                (tableRow[index].style.display = "");
            } else {
              return mapFunctions.searchFuncReasult === "array" ?
                results.push(row) :
                (tableRow[index].style.display = "none");
            }
          }
        });
      };

      return (
        <WrappedComponent {...props} handleSearch={handleSearch} /> 
      );
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: Does this work? `export default MyHoc(connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(MyComponent), mapFunctions)`? What errors are you having? Besides that you're trying to return from a `forEach`, which doesn't do anything?

Comment: Please show us what you tried and what errors you were getting.

Comment: the for each iterate all the rows ```tr``` in the table and gives an array of second index of each table row ```td``` which could be the names column then it returns an array with matching results from the input[type="search"] or deletes tables rows that don't match

Comment: ```export default MyHoc(connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(MyComponent), mapFunctions)``` This works fine if I'm doing it in the component I'm wrapping in the hoc but I want to put my redux in the hoc so that I don't have to import redux every time I want to use the hoc @ZacAnger

Comment: "I structured my HOC so it could be invoked twice 'functional programming'." Can you elaborate on what you mean here? "Now I'm failing to connect redux to get state and some functions." Where are you trying to do this? "Everything I have tried has resulted in an error being thrown." Can you demonstrate what you've tried and what the errors are? Based on your last comment I think I've pieced together that you want to use redux ***within*** this HOC. Is this correct? What do you need to select from state? Are there any actions you need to inject? Please provide more context.

Comment: Yes! you understood exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I want to get state from redux like an array of objects with drugs and drug details, after importing redux I want to put the common logic like searching the same array of drugs or even different array. This functionality is required in almost 10 pages so I want to just import the **HOC** in which it passes the ```handleSearch``` as props to the ```WrappedComponent``` I approach it like a cross-cutting concern. So I'll just call the ```handleSearch( event , tableID )``` in the ```WrappedComponent```

Comment: the normal way of structuring a hoc is:

```
    import React from 'react'

    export default (WrappedComponent) => {
       const hocComponent = ({ ...props }) => < WrappedComponent { ...props }/>

       return hocComponent
}

```
my case is
```
   import React from "react";

   export default (WrappedComponent) => {
    return (mapFunctions) => {

    ...code here

    return function({ ...props }) {
      return <WrappedComponent { ...props }/>;
     };
    };
   };
```
@DrewReese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to connect the wrapped component to redux *within* your Higher Order Component, then you can refactor your HOC to define an "inner" functional component that can then also be wrapped by the `conenct` Higher Order Component (*Alternatively you could use react-redux's `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks in the component directly*).

```
import React from "react"

export default (WrappedComponent) => (mapFunctions) => {
  const component = (props) => { // <-- will contain inject props from Redux
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    // typical functionality of the HOC
    //search function
    const handleSearch = (e) => {
      let filter,
        table,
        tableRow,
        tableCells,
        txtValue,
        results = [];

      filter = e.currentTarget.value.toLowerCase();
      table = document.querySelector(`#${mapFunctions.tableID}`);
      tableRow = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

      Array.from(tableRow).forEach((row, index) => {
        tableCells = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

        if (tableCells) {
          txtValue = tableCells.textContent || tableCells.innerText;
          if (txtValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            return mapFunctions.searchFuncReasult === "array"
              ? results.push(row)
              : (tableRow[index].style.display = "");
          } else {
            return mapFunctions.searchFuncReasult === "array"
              ? results.push(row)
              : (tableRow[index].style.display = "none");
          }
        }
      });
    };

    return <WrappedComponent {...props} handleSearch={handleSearch} />;
  };

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    // ... any redux state selectors
  });

  const mapDispatchToProps = {
    // ... any redux action creators
  };

  return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(component);
};
```

Another common pattern I use when combining several HOCs to decorate a component is to compose them together. If you are using `react-redux` then you likely are already using `redux` as a dependency, which exports such a `compose` utility. You likely already used it to compose all your reducers into a single root reducer. In my opinion this is the simpler solution, especially since it doesn't appear you *actually* need the injected redux props ***in*** your HOC wrapper.

```
import { compose } from 'redux';

...

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  YourCustomHOC
)(ComponentYouWantToWrap)(customMapFunctions);
```

If you invert the order of the arguments to your HOC

```
export default (mapFunctions) => (WrappedComponent) => {
```

then you can simplify the composition a bit

```
export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  YourCustomHOC(customMapFunctions),
)(ComponentYouWantToWrap);
```